# Python, I'm trying to create this kind of argument -active=YES

Tags: python, linux, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm a newbie to programming using python.

I have to create a script that ask for some argument.

So did this:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "n:h", ["server-name=","help"])
for option, value in opts:
if option in ('-h', '--help'):
    show_usage()
elif option in ('-n', '--server-name'):
    serverName = value
```

evrithing it's OK:

```
./myscript -a www.site.com
```

BUT i'm asking how can i add this kind of argument

```
./myscript -a www.site.com -active=YES
```

Comment: Why can't use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getopt` expects the argument to be of the style `--active=YES`. If you are happy with the double dash at the start (as shown) then you want to modify the first line of your code to be:

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "n:h", ["server-name=","help","active="])
```

and then add an appropriate conditional statement to your loop